# Javascript Partial number match

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to create partial RegEx match in JS. What I want to achieve is that when user enters something inside input field, JS will always do partial match for number sequence on key press, not only when whole RegEx match is fulfilled.

So, this is the RegEx rule:

```
^[12][^1-6]\d{2}$
```

When user enters number 1 or 2, that is correct match, but 3 is incorrect. Next, when numbers between 1 and 6 are not entered, that is also correct, and at last any 2 next numbers are correct. As I said, right now RegEx match is fulfilled only when all 4 numbers are entered.

How can I achieve partial input check?

Comment: if you want to match a string that _starts_ with something, just remove `$` from your regexp.

Comment: `2x` should be a valid match?

Comment: Are you sure that the second character should be anything but 1,2,3,4,5 or 6? Do you really want a space, line feed, ö, € or other characters here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest solution is to wrap optional components into the corresponding `(?:)?` construct. You actually have two optional components, so you need to take that into account.

The result will look like...

```
^[12](?:[^1-6]\d{0,2})?$
```

... as you have to match both '2x', '2x1', and '2x11', it seems. ) Hence `{0,2}` quantifier.

The problem obviously is that you cannot use a *single* regex to check whether a user finished entering some value into your field - or not. In other words, if you want the 'intermediate' `1` to match, but the resulting `1` not to match, well, it's just impossible to do with a single regex check. )

Comment: In this case it is enough with `^[12]([^1-6]\d{0,2})?$` but I thik niksy want `^[12]([1-6]\d{0,2})?$`.

Comment: Yes, this is it, later I figured out to use `{0,2}` quantifier but non-capturing group was the missing element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can "or" your regex, but it means duplication:

```
^([12]|[12][^1-6]|[12][^1-6]\d{2})$
```

To break this down:

```
^      From the start of the string / line
       match either
[12]   The numbers 1 or 2
|      or
[12]   The numbers 1 or 2
       followed by
[^1-6] Any character which is not the numbers 1 through 6
|      or
[12]   The numbers 1 or 2
       followed by
[^1-6] Any character which is not the numbers 1 through 6
       followed by
\d     Any number
{2}    repeated two times
$      followed by the end of the string / line
```

That will match any of the following:

```
1
2
1N
2N
1NXX
2NXX
```

Where `N` is anything which is not the numbers 1 through 6 and `X` is any number.

Note: If you really want to match only the numbers 0, and 7-9 in the second part of your regex simply change `[^1-6]` to `[07-9]`.

Comment: Yes, this is one way to go and it works, just one little edit is needed - quantifier `{0,2}` for matching any range of numbers from 0 to 2. Thanks!